# JSF 1.1: Placeholder {0} of required inputText won't be replaced

Tags: jsf

I have the following JSF code for a required input textfield:

```
<h:inputText id="System"                        
         label="System"
         value="#{MyBean.system}"
         maxlength="2"
         required="true">
```

Then when the user does not input the value for this field, the following message is displayed: "{0}: A value is required." The issue is: **JSF is not replacing the placeholder {0} with the inputText's id**, as it was supposed to do.

I have this kind of code all over my system and it was previously working well. Recently I switched to a build using Maven and I'm likely to have changed the version of some lib, which is now causing the application not to work properly. I tried to make sure the versions of the libs declared in my POM match the ones I had before but even son this problem sticks.

The JSF-related libraries declared in my POM are the following (plus I'm using JBoss 4.0.5 GA):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Any clues?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in JSF 1.1. This was introduced in JSF 1.2.

Upgrade to JSF 1.2. It's 100% compatible on a JSF 1.1 environment. Additional bonus is that many, many logic and performance bugs are fixed in latest JSF 1.2.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to JSF 1.2 (changed the version of MyFaces to 1.2.9), but it was to no avail. I also get this warning now: Digester] [NavigationRuleRule]{faces-config/navigation-rule} Merge(/*).

Comment: It also shows these messages in my console (it was being displayed before as well):        "14:26:32,988 INFO  [MyfacesConfig] Starting up Tomahawk on the RI-JSF-Implementation.
14:26:32,988 INFO  [MyfacesConfig] Starting up Tomahawk on the MyFaces-JSF-Implementation
14:26:32,988 ERROR [MyfacesConfig] Both MyFaces and the RI are on your classpath. Please make sure to use only one of the two JSF-implementations."

Comment: That suggests that the server where you're deploying your webapp to has Mojarra already bundled.

Comment: I checked the lib folder of my JBoss instalation and there's no jsf-impl there. What I do noticed is that richfaces depends on jsf-impl (which is the RI). Is there a way to "instruct" richfaces to use myfaces instead of RI?

Comment: No, your current problem is that your webapp's runtime classpath contains both MyFaces and Mojarra/RI. You need to get rid of one of them. You can't tell the server/webapp/RichFaces which one it should be using. Provided that you're absolutely positive that it isn't JBoss fault, then it's likely Maven's fault. Explore the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the Maven-produced WAR. It should not contain Mojarra/RI JARs, provided that you want to go the MyFaces path. Just tell Maven to exclude Mojarra from the build. Maven is completely beyond me, so I can't assist you in detail.

Comment: Made some tweaks here, but now I'm getting the following exception when I try to log on the application (the login page is displayed correctly) => javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:221)

Comment: That can happen if your `web.xml` is not declared conform Servlet 2.4. Make sure that it's declared conform Servlet 2.4 (with a XSD) and thus not 2.3 or older (with a DTD).

Comment: Yes. My web.xml's version attribute is appropriately set to 2.4. Enabling the debug here, I get this: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer. Looks like I'm missing some lib.

Comment: Oh, it's just a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Well, apparently Maven has polluted the `/WEB-INF/lib` of the built WAR with a servlet-container specific `jsp-api.jar` file originating from an older versioned container or so.

Comment: Actually I don't have any jsp-api.jar in my /WEB-INF/lib of the built WAR. Tried to include one, but the error continues...